# How to use this selector in the jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a drag and drop resizable template engine. I'm having a problem that I think isn't hard to fix, but I'm stuck.

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$(".getInfo").click(function(){
$("b").mousemove(function(){
        var bodyColor =  $("#bgcolor").css("backgroundColor");

$(this).css("background-color",bodyColor);
});

});
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div  id="resizable1" class="drag resize getInfo">
<h3 class="ui-widget-header">slide show</h3>
</div>
```

**DEMO IMAGE**

[image]

**I need to have this**.

When the user clicks on any div where the class name is `.getinfo` and the user clicks any color in the colorpicker I want to assign it to the clicked div. I was try using above code but had no luck.

Comment: Binding a mousemove event inside a click handler that can be triggered more than once isn't a very good idea.

Comment: can you show me how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bind your `mousemove` for the colour picker inside that `click`. They need to be separate. Try this:

```
var bodyColor = "#FFFFFF"; //declared globally, default to a color

$("b").mousemove(function(){
    bodyColor =  $("#bgcolor").css("backgroundColor");
});

$(".getInfo").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color",bodyColor);
});
```

Comment: $("b").mousemove(function(){}); I'll get the colopicker value from here.So i can't remove it ?